# class is not-key value coding compliant error yet everything in the storyboard is correct

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting a key-value coding compliant error loading a view from a xib.
Of course I've had this error many times in the past and know it means there's an invalid or missing outlet connection. However I simply cannot see anything wrong in this instance and have deleted and reconnected everything but the error won't go away.

Here we can see the file's owner is of type TCUsageAlertView and there are three outlets:
[image]

[image]

[image]

And here they are connected to the owner

[image]

And we can see the TCUsageAlertView is indeed a UIView:

```
@interface TCUsageAlertView : UIView
{
….
```

And here's where the view gets loaded:

```
TCUsageAlertView *dialog = (TCUsageAlertView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UsageAlertDialog" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

There is only one view in the xib so objectAtIndex:0 is fine.

If I delete the outlets in the Connections Inspector then the class will load, if I put them back then it fails. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files owner is whatever you passed into loadNibNamed... in this case it is an instance of whatever class is loading the view, NOT an instance of TCUsageAlertView.

The outer level view should be changed to class TCUsageAlertView and then the connection should be made from that view to the subviews.

Comment: Thanks but I want the loading class to be a view controller which loads and displays the view therefore the outer class cannot be changed to a TCUsageAlertView. This is a pattern I've used before in another project and thus is possible. I double checked how I'm doing it in that project and compared with this and the only difference was the owner in IB was set to NSObject. But after making that corresponding change in this project I still get the same problem.

Comment: Not suggesting you change the loading class.  You have a view in your ib that contains the 3 labels.  It looks as if the class of that should be TCUsageAlertView (and the outlets changed)  Right now the problem is that the outlets are from Files Owner which is your view controller class which doesn't have the 3 relevant properties.

Comment: Gotcha, and that's how have it in my other project, didn't notice.